# Selecting a select with on(change) is causing the browser to go to a new URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

Basically, I have four select boxes I'm using to filter results of a list.  the problem arises when I select one of the select boxes, it goes to a URL that has the select option's value in it.  For instance, if I select an option that has the value of "2", it will take me to "mysite.com/2"

Here is my javascript:

```
jQuery(function($) {  

$('.options').on('change', function() {

  type      = $('#type').val().trim();
  services  = $('#services').val().trim();
  location  = $('#location').val().trim();
  language  = $('#language').val().trim();


  $(".card").hide().filter(function() { 
    var show = true;
    show = (
      (jQuery.inArray(type, typearray) != -1) && 
      (jQuery.inArray(services, servicesarray) != -1) && 
      (jQuery.inArray(location, locationarray) != -1) && 
      (jQuery.inArray(language, languagearray) != -1) 
    );

    return show;
  }).show();

});


});
```

Also, while I'm here, I'm also looking to hide select options in my select menus depending on whether they have any search results available based on the other selected options.

my HTML is here:

```
      <select id="type" class="options"><option value='3'>Youth Empowerment Services</option><option value='2'>Child and Family Services</option><option value='4'>Intellectual or Developmental Disabilities</option><option value='5'>Substance Abuse Managed Service</option></select>        
                    <select id="services" class="options"><option value="111">Service A</option><option value="112">Service B</option><option value="113">Service C</option><option value="114">Service D</option><option value="115">Service E</option><option value="116">Service F</option><option value="117">Service G</option><option value="118">Service H</option><option value="119">Service I</option></select>        

                    <select id="location" class="options"><option value="201">Location A</option><option value="202">Location B</option><option value="203">Location C</option></select>  

    <select id="language" class="options"><option value='17'>Spanish</option><option value='18'>Vietnamese</option><option value='16'>English</option></select>        

    <ul id="results" class="list">










        <li class="card" data-type="[5]" data-service="[117 , 118 , 119 , ]" data-location="[201 , 201 , 201 , ]" data-language="[16]">
          <h1>Provider C</h1>
          <strong>Provider Type:</strong> <br />
          <a href="http://taxonomytest.dev/provider_type/substance-abuse-managed-service/" rel="tag">Substance Abuse Managed Service</a><br /><br />
          <strong>Language:</strong><br />
          <a href="http://taxonomytest.dev/language/english/" rel="tag">English</a><br /><br />

                  <strong>Services:</strong><br />

                        <ins>Service G</ins><br />
                        Location A<br /><br />

                        <ins>Service H</ins><br />
                        Location A<br /><br />

                        <ins>Service I</ins><br />
                        Location A<br /><br />

        </li>









        <li class="card" data-type="[4]" data-service="[114 , 115 , 116 , ]" data-location="[201 , 202 , 203 , ]" data-language="[16 , 17]">
          <h1>Provider B</h1>
          <strong>Provider Type:</strong> <br />
          <a href="http://taxonomytest.dev/provider_type/intellectual-or-developmental-disabilities/" rel="tag">Intellectual or Developmental Disabilities</a><br /><br />
          <strong>Language:</strong><br />
          <a href="http://taxonomytest.dev/language/english/" rel="tag">English</a>, <a href="http://taxonomytest.dev/language/spanish/" rel="tag">Spanish</a><br /><br />

                  <strong>Services:</strong><br />

                        <ins>Service D</ins><br />
                        Location A<br /><br />

                        <ins>Service E</ins><br />
                        Location B<br /><br />

                        <ins>Service F</ins><br />
                        Location C<br /><br />

        </li>









        <li class="card" data-type="[2]" data-service="[111 , 112 , 113 , ]" data-location="[201 , 202 , 203 , ]" data-language="[16 , 18]">
          <h1>Test Type A</h1>
          <strong>Provider Type:</strong> <br />
          <a href="http://taxonomytest.dev/provider_type/child-and-family-services/" rel="tag">Child and Family Services</a><br /><br />
          <strong>Language:</strong><br />
          <a href="http://taxonomytest.dev/language/english/" rel="tag">English</a>, <a href="http://taxonomytest.dev/language/vietnamese/" rel="tag">Vietnamese</a><br /><br />

                  <strong>Services:</strong><br />

                        <ins>Service A</ins><br />
                        Location A<br /><br />

                        <ins>Service B</ins><br />
                        Location B<br /><br />

                        <ins>Service C</ins><br />
                        Location C<br /><br />

        </li>

    </ul>
```

For instance, if Type 2 is selected, I want only service 111,112,113 to show up in the select.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for two different things in one question; if that is the case please create two questions. For each a [mcve] created with the snippet tool (`<>` button in the editor) is most helpful. [ask]

Comment: thanks, will seperate into a seperate question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the scope your variable "location" is in. It's setting `window.location` to the value of `$('#location').val().trim();` which redirects the page. You need to scope your variables to not be global. Declaring them like this will do the trick:

```
var type      = $('#type').val().trim();
var services  = $('#services').val().trim();
var location  = $('#location').val().trim();
var language  = $('#language').val().trim();
```